# Facetapi combined filter of city and zip code

Tags: 7, ajax, search, entities

I am using address field module with search api and facetapi modules.

I want one filter of two fields, city and zip code. Which will be an autocomplete field.

I have used the [Search API Combined Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_combined) module. Created a combined fields filter with the following configurations:

```
Imitate field : Address » Locality (i.e. City)
Contained fields : Address » Locality (i.e. City), Address » Postal code
```

But the problem is, in facet settings I can see only links and links with checkboxes widgets. there is no autocomplete widget.

and second when I select one of a widget from links and links with checkboxes, it only displays the city names on the search page.

can anyone know the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [search_api_combined](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_combined).

In the search index, there will be a new tab with the name "autocomplete". Go to that tab and select your view and save the settings.

Then in the view filter, select your desired field and make it expose filter.

And also make that combined field a multivalue field with type *full text*.